# ffmpeg with many input and filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 3.mp3 \
       -filter_complex "\
          [0]volume=1[a0]; \
          [1]adelay=1000[a1]; \
          [2]adelay=2000[a2]; \
          [3]adelay=3000[a3]; \
          [a0][a1][a2][a3]amix=4:duration=first" \
-y merged.mp3
```

But I have many input. more than 500. so my pattern is be like this:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 3.mp3 ... [n.mp3] \
       -filter_complex "\
          [0]volume=1[a0]; \
          [1]adelay=1000[a1]; \
          [2]adelay=2000[a2]; \
          [3]adelay=3000[a3]; \
          :
          :
          [n]adelay=1000000[aN]; \
          [a0][a1][a2][a3] ... [aN] amix=[n]:duration=first" \
-y merged.mp3
```

But I get errors in any platform.

Linux:

```
:
:
Input #200, mp3, from 'sounds2/200.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.95, start: 0.069063, bitrate: 24 kb/s
    Stream #200:0: Audio: mp3, 16000 Hz, mono, s16p, 24 kb/s
[amix @ 0x3cffb20] Value 201.000000 for parameter 'inputs' out of range [1 - 32]
    Last message repeated 1 times
[amix @ 0x3cffb20] Error setting option inputs to value 201.
[Parsed_amix_201 @ 0x3cffa60] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x3b44980] Error initializing filter 'amix' with args '201:duration=first'
Error configuring filters.
```

Cygwin:

```
  Stream #199:0 (mp3) -> adelay
  Stream #200:0 (mp3) -> adelay
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_adelay_171 @ 00000000041fc0c0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_adelay_171
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #200:0
Conversion failed!
```

Windows:

```
The command line is too long.
```

What's your solution?

Comment: The output tells you exactly what's wrong. If you want to mix more than 32 inputs get ffmpeg 3.4 or newer (max 1024).

Comment: @aergistal Thanks for help, I upgrade and resolve that error, but this solution is very very slow, I try with 559 sounds input, show me: `size=       0kB time=00:00:00.42 bitrate=   4.7kbits/s speed=0.0176x`. The `0.0176x` is very very slow, Maybe is there another solution, be like pattern in input or use input file mode... also if my files more then 1024 what's solution?!

Comment: Now I working on split jobs to merge 50 to 50 parts, but have problem with destroy volume sounds in each part...